Symmetry breaking in spin-1 Stern-Gerlach
Say you send a beam of random spin-1 particles down a Stern-Gerlach machine, block out the middle path, and recombine the beams.  You should have particles that are in a state $(1,0,1)/\sqrt{2}$ in the $J_z$ basis.  Send that beam down an x-axis Stern-Gerlach machine and everything is fine - you get half the particles $J_x=+\hbar$, half with $J_x=-\hbar$ and none with 0.  However, if you send the same beam down a y-axis Stern-Gerlach, then you find all the particles have $J_y=0$.  I've tried this several different ways and always get the same answer.
The fact that blocking $J_z=0$ breaks the symmetry between $x$ and $y$ seems very strange to me.  Is there a physical explanation for why that should be the case?  Or did I do something illegal by blocking a piece of a beam and combining the leftovers with no phase shift?  Or maybe it's because the particles are (at least implicitly) moving in the $y$-direction, so I shouldn't expect there to be any symmetry?

In which direction is the beam, is it in direction $y$? The modified state expression may depend on this direction. Can you show the result explicitly with matrices  $J_x,J_y$?


Say you send a beam of random spin-1 particles down a Stern-Gerlach machine, block out the middle path, and recombine the beams.  You should have particles that are in a state $(1,0,1)/\sqrt{2}$ in the $J_z$ basis.

You are asserting that you "should have" particles that are in a state $(1,0,1)/\sqrt{2}$ after you "recombine the beams," but it is not clear why you think you can assert such a thing.

The fact that blocking $J_z=0$ breaks the symmetry between $x$ and $y$ seems very strange to me.

Right, it does seem very strange. Because, given the parameters of this specific question, such a symmetry breaking can't be reasonably understood.

Is there a physical explanation for why that should be the case?

No, because it is not the case.

Anyways, if you want to consider an equal statistical mixture of $|S_z;+1\rangle$ and $|S_z;-1\rangle$, you should not work with a state, but rather with a density matrix:
$$
\hat \rho = \frac{1}{2}|S_z;+1\rangle\langle S_z;+1| + \frac{1}{2}|S_z;-1\rangle\langle S_z; -1|\;.
$$
You can then show that
$$
Tr(\hat \rho |S_x; j\rangle\langle S_x; j|) = Tr(\hat \rho |S_y; j\rangle\langle S_y; j|)\;,
$$
for all $j=-1,0,+1$.

Update:
Suppose that you really do have some coherent, but arbitrary, initial state.
In the $S_z$ basis, I can write the state as:
$$
|\Psi_{in}\rangle \equiv (\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \equiv \alpha|-1\rangle + \beta|0\rangle + \gamma|+1\rangle\;.
$$
Suppose further that the "blocking" of one beam and subsequent "recombination" can be described as a partial measurement. In such a case the partial measurement rule says that the state after the "measurement" is:
$$
|\Psi_{out}\rangle=\frac{(\alpha, 0, \beta)}{|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2}\;.
$$
Or, in terms of two real parameters
$$
|\Psi_{out}\rangle=\sin(\theta)|-1\rangle + \cos(\theta)e^{i\phi}|+1\rangle\;.
$$
The probability to measure $S_x=0$ in this state is:
$$
P(S_x=0)=\frac{1}{2}(1-2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi))\;.
$$
The probability to measure $S_y=0$ in this state is:
$$
P(S_y=0)=\frac{1}{2}(1+2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi))\;.
$$
So
$$
P(S_x=0)+P(S_y=0) = 1
$$

Thanks.  So essentially, since the source is incoherent, I should think of each individual particle as being in $(1,0,e^{i\theta})/\sqrt{2}$, and the graceful way to marginalize over $\theta$ is via the density matrix.


"Because it can't happen." The direction of beam introduces apparent preferred direction (maybe it is $y$ in OP?), so the system is not symmetric wrt $x,y$.


@JánLalinský "maybe it is $y$ in OP?" And maybe it is $x$ in OP. Which one is it? We don't know, so how can there be a preferred direction?

But there is a preferred direction in the SG setup, the direction of the beam (also, the magnet has a preferred direction perpendicular to $z$, and is usually oriented to coincide with the beam direction). We just do not know from OP if it coincides with $x$ or $y$ or some linear combination of these two. If algebra with $(1,0,1)$ shows measurement of $J_y$ is unexpected, then maybe $y$ is the beam direction.

@JánLalinský But OP has not told us this. OP is just making some unfounded assumption about the dynamics of recombining beams. Of course if the state really is (1,0,1) then it is an eigenstate of $S_y$ with eigenvalue zero, but why should it emerge from this hypothetical recombination in such a state? There is no reason.

(Or there may be a reason, but I don't know what it is.)

I agree OP lacks explanation of why the procedure results in $(1,0,1)$. However, it seems plausible, as it treats +1 and -1 spin projection on axis $z$ equally. What other quantum state would be plausible as well? They all seem to prefer +1 or -1.

@JánLalinský Yes, if the blocking of the beam is a projective partial measurement then the state after measurement will only have the $+1$ and $-1$ components. But one can't know the final state unless the initial state has been specified, which OP didn't do. (But even if OP had specified the initial state, I still don't see how the direction in which the beam is traveling can have an effect at this level of detail... the spin and space translation is not coupled in any simple way as far as I can see...)

And I softened by "it can't happen," since I guess maybe it can... but I still don't entirely see how it could...

Your analysis is mostly correct (and the point is interesting). You have analyzed the case where the coherence between the beams is preserved when they are recombined. This is difficult to do, experimentally, but not impossible. In such a recombination the final state will be
$$
(1,0,e^{i\alpha}) / \sqrt{2}
$$
where the phase $\alpha$ depends on the lengths of the paths in the two arms of the apparatus which recombine the beams. The apparatus could be arranged such that $\alpha=0$ and then you get the case you treated.
This also shows where the symmetry breaking occurs: it is in the apparatus to recombine the beams.

"In such a recombination the final state will be" This is not necessarily the case. Even in the case of a partial measurement on a coherent state, the final state depends on the initial state, which OP did not specify. For example, if the initial state is $|S_z;+1\rangle$ the final state will also be that state after the partial measurement.

(I guess OP did specify a "beam of random spin-1 particles," but I'm not sure if OP means the particles are described by a coherent state like $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ for arbitrary alpha, beta, and gamma, up to normalization, or what...)
